# How can I set the numbering parameters for subfigures back to default?

Tags: floats, subfloats, subfig, renewcommand

Please I did change the numbering parameters for subfigures using:

```
\newcounter{row}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subfigure}{row}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{row}.\arabic{subfigure}}
```

and it worked perfectly, Now I would like to come back to the default parameters for the rest of the figures.
What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: @Mensch I am using a journal Template. As for the document class, it is: ` \documentclass[]{interact} `

Comment: Why don't you simply enclose your custom settings within braces (`{}`)? Place your customisations and the required figure(s) within braces. The remaining figures won't be affected.